# Inoperative dropdown menu & tooltip text(A dropdown menu that does not work)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I added "tooltip text" to the "dropdown menu" that worked on "navbar" and it did not work properly. I do not know why, but the same "tooltip text" came from every "anchor".

I do not know about bootstrap, so when I put "popover" in place of "tooltip text", it does not work until "popover" and "dropdonw menu".

More funny is that "dropdonw menu" works well in Eclipse, but it is not open at all in Chrome browser
 It is. Of course, if you open it with Eclipse open with web browser, dropdown menu works well. Of course there is no popover there.
I actually want to show the tooltip text rather than the popover.
Why? Can I use them in the navbar together?

It seems to be long because there are many comments, but html is short.The menu is in Korean, so please read it with care. thank.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine (even in intranet) & Chrome Frame Remove this if you use the .htaccess -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <title>Photolog::{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>

    <!-- Replace favicon.ico & apple-touch-icon.png in the root of your domain and delete these references -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">                <!-- '17.06.08 Iee -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>                                 <!-- '17.06.08 Iee -->
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js">    </script>              <!-- '17.06.08 Iee -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/4.3.1/css/fileinput.min.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="photolog" charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static',filename='css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" type="text/css" media="screen" title="photolog" charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static',filename='css/font-awesome.min.css')}}" type="text/css" media="screen" title="photolog" charset="UTF-8" />
    <!--link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static',filename='css/jasny-fileinput.css')}}" type="text/css" media="screen" title="photolog" charset="UTF-8" /-->
    <!--link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static',filename='css/style.css')}}" type="text/css" media="screen" title="photolog" charset="UTF-8" /-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static',filename='css/placeholder-error.css')}}" type="text/css" media="screen" title="photolog" charset="UTF-8" />

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{url_for('static',filename='js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{url_for('static',filename='js/bootbox.min.js')}}"></script>
    <!--script type="text/javascript" src="{{url_for('static',filename='js/jasny-fileinput.js')}}"></script-->
    <!--script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{url_for('static',filename='js/gmaps.js')}}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{url_for('static',filename='js/exif.js')}}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{url_for('static',filename='js/binaryajax.js')}}"></script>
    <!--<script $(document).popover() {tri'show'){   $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover(  {container: "body"}) ;  </script>  --> <!-- '17. 5.29 Iee -->
    <script> 
        $(function() {  $('.example-popover').popover({ container: 'body'  })})
        $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
    </script>   <!-- '17. 6. 8 Iee -->
    <!-- <script $(document).ready(function(){  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip( {delay: { "show":0, "hide":111000 }); }); </script>  --> <!-- '17. 5.29 Iee -->
    <!--    $(document).ready(function() { $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({container: "body"}); });  --> 
      {% block head %}{% endblock %}


    Ext.define('ext5.view.chapter7.BigDataGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.chapter7-bigdatagrid',
    requires: [
        'Ext.grid.column.RowNumberer',
        'Ext.data.proxy.JsonP'
    ],
    width: 700,
    height: 280,

    columnLines: true,

    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;
        var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {  // #1
            fields: [
                {
                    name: 'title'
                },
                {
                    name: 'forumtitle'
                },
                {
                    name: 'forumid',
                    type: 'int'
                },
                {
                    name: 'username'
                },
                {
                    name: 'replycount',
                    type: 'int'
                },
                {
                    name: 'lastpost',
                    type: 'date',
                    dateFormat: 'timestamp'
                },
                'lastposter'
            ],
            pageSize: 10,
            buffered: true,
            proxy: {
                type: 'jsonp',
                url: 'http://www.sencha.com/forum/remote_topics/index.php',
                reader: {
                    rootProperty: 'topics',
                    totalProperty: 'totalCount'
                }
            },
            autoLoad: true
        });
        Ext.apply(this, {
            dockedItems: [
                {
                    dock: 'bottom',
                    xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',     // #2
                    store: store
                },
                {
                    dock: 'top',
                    xtype: 'toolbar',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'component',     // #3
                            itemId: 'status',
                            tpl: '전체 게시물 : {count}',
                            style: 'margin-left:15px'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            store: store,
            columns: this.getColumnConfig()
        });
        me.callParent(arguments);
        me.store.on('datachanged', me.onStoreSizeChange, me);  // #4
    },

    onStoreSizeChange: function () {    // #5
        this.down('#status').update({count: this.store.getTotalCount()});
    },

    getColumnConfig: function () {
        var me = this;
        return   [
            {
                xtype: 'rownumberer',
                width: 50,
                sortable: false,
                renderer: function (value, meta, record, row, col, store) {
                    // #6
                    return store.getTotalCount() - row - ((store.currentPage - 1) * store.pageSize);
                }
            },
            {
                text: "Topic",
                dataIndex: 'title',
                flex: 1,
                sortable: false
            },
            {
                text: "Author",
                dataIndex: 'username',
                width: 100,
                hidden: true,
                sortable: false
            },
            {
                text: "Replies",
                dataIndex: 'replycount',
                align: 'center',
                width: 70,
                sortable: false
            },
            {
                id: 'last',
                text: "Last Post",
                dataIndex: 'lastpost',
                width: 130,
                renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('n/j/Y g:i A'),
                sortable: false
            }
        ];
    }
});
</head>

<body width="100%">




 <!--  Navbar start  ================================================================================================-->   
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">                                  <!-- fluid 좌우로 꽉 찬/container 고정폭  --> 
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>      <!-- screen reader only - to hide info intended only for screen readers from the layout of the rendered page.-->
                    <span class="fa fa-bar"></span>     <!--  span 시작한 후 <i> 태그를 사용하여 어디서든 글꼴 썸네일 아이콘을 배치 할 수 있습니다. -->
                    <span class="fa fa-bar"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" style="color:#ffff00;"  href="{{url_for('photolog.index')}}">&nbsp; <i class="fa fa-picture-o"  
                data-toggle="popover" data-container="body" data-placement="top" title="하남지사의 IWS" data-content="하남지사의 Intelligence Workshop System입니다." 
                    data-trigger="hover"> </i> <B>하남</B>  </a>         <!--   Web Site Brand  -->
                <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" style="color:#ffff00;" href="{{url_for('photolog.index')}}">&nbsp; <i data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top"class="fa fa-picture-o" ></i>SMeMap</a>  -->     

           </div>   
 <!--  Navbar start  ======================== 파일 수신 종료 =============================================================-->                

           <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">               
               <ul class="nav navbar-nav">                        
                    <!-- <li class="active"><a href="{{url_for('photolog.upload_photo_form')}}" ><i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-large"  
                    data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" > </i><B> 정보 관리 </B></a></li> -->
                    <li class="active"><a href="{{url_for('photolog.upload_photo_form')}}" ><i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-large" data-toggle="popover" 
                                data-container="body" data-placement="bottom" title=" " data-content="카메라와 서버 간의 데이타 통신 중지" data-trigger="hover"></i> 정보 관리 </a></li>  


 <!--  Navbar start  ======================= 관리/설정   ==================================================================-->       
                      <li class="dropdown">

                        <a class="dropdown_toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="{{url_for('photolog.show_map')}}" ><i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-large"  data-container="body" 
                        data-placement="top" title="관리자를 위한 메뉴" data-content="각종 설정 및 등록과 같은 관리자가 사용하는 기능"> </i> <data-trigger="hover"> <B>관리/설정</B> <span class="caret"> </span></a> 
                        <!-- <a class="dropdown_toggle" data-toggle="dropdown popover" href="{{url_for('photolog.show_map')}}" ><i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-large"  data-container="body" 
                        data-placement="top" title="관리자를 위한 메뉴" data-content="각종 설정 및 등록과 같은 관리자가 사용하는 기능"> </i> <data-trigger="hover"> <B>관리/설정</B> <span class="caret"> </span></a> -->

                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a class="ddmenu" href="{{url_for('photolog.upload_photo_form')}}"> <i class="fa fa-map-o fa-large" data-toggle="popover"  data-container="body"
                                        data-placement="right" title=" " data-content="좌표, 위/경도, 주소 입력 등 현재 위치 설정"> </i> <data-trigger="hover"> 지도 설정</a></li> 


                                    <li><a class="ddmenu" href="{{url_for('photolog.upload_photo_form')}}"> <i  class="fa fa-map-o fa-large" data-toggle="popover" data-container="body" 
                                        data-placement="right" title=" " data-content="설정 위치 인근에 설치될 카메라 일반사항의 등록"></i> <data-trigger="hover"> 카메라 등록</a></li>   


                                    <li><a class="ddmenu" href="{{url_for('photolog.upload_photo_form')}}"> <i  class="fa fa-map-o fa-large" data-toggle="popover" data-container="body"  
                                        data-placement="right"  title=" " data-content="지도 상 표기할 각종 아이콘 선정"></i> <data-trigger="hover">  아이콘 등록</a></li>   

                                    <li><a class="ddmenu" href="{{url_for('photolog.upload_photo_form')}}"> <i  class="fa fa-map-o fa-large" data-toggle="popover" data-container="body" 
                                        data-placement="right"   title=" " data-content="운행 파악시 문자 연락을 해야 하는 유의 차량 등록"></i> <data-trigger="hover"> 유의차량 등록</a></li>                                     

                                    <li><a class="ddmenu" href="{{url_for('photolog.upload_photo_form')}}"> <i  class="fa fa-map-o fa-large" data-toggle="popover" data-container="body" 
                                       data-placement="right"  title=" " data-content="유의 차량 운행시 문자 연락 대상자 등록"></i> <data-trigger="hover"> SMS수신처 등록</a></li>                                               


                               <!-- data-container="body" data-placement="top" title="관리자를 위한 메뉴" data-content="각종 설정 및 등록과 같은 관리자가 사용하는 기능"> </i> <B>관리/설정</B> <span class="caret"> |</span></a>   -->                                                 
                               <!-- <a class="dropdown_toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="{{url_for('photolog.show_map')}}" ><i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-large" >  
                                       </i> <B>관리/설정</B> <span class="caret"></span></a>       
                                            <li><a class="ddmenu" href="{{url_for('photolog.upload_photo_form')}}"> <i class="fa fa-map-o fa-large" ></i> 지도 설정</a></li>  
                                            <li><a class="ddmenu" href="{{url_for('photolog.show_map')}}"><i class="fa fa-map-o fa-large"></i> 카메라 등록</a></li>                                              
                                            <li><a class="ddmenu" href="{{url_for('photolog.show_map')}}" ><i class="fa fa-map-o fa-large"></i>  아이콘 등록</a></li>                                    
                                            <li><a class="ddmenu" href="{{url_for('photolog.show_map')}}" ><i class="fa fa-map-o fa-large"></i> 유의차량 등록</a></li>            
                                            <li><a class="ddmenu" href="{{url_for('photolog.show_map')}}" ><i class="fa fa-map-o fa-large"></i> SMS수신처 등록</a></li>  -->                                                                             
                            </ul>
                      </li> 
 <!--  Navbar start  ======================= 조회/통계   ==================================================================-->                                                   
                        <li class="dropdown">

                             <a  class="dropdown_toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"  href="{{url_for('photolog.show_all')}}" ><i class="fa fa-th-list fa-large" data-container="body" 
                             data-placement="top"  title="특정 시점, 기간 중 자료 관리" data-content="특정 시점의  또는 특정 기간 중의 출입차량에 대한 리포트"></i> <B> 각종 조회  </B> <span class="caret"></span></a>   

                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">                                      

                                    <li><a class="ddmenu"  href="{{url_for('photolog.show_map')}}" class="fa fa-th-list fa-large"> <i data-toggle="popover" data-container="body" 
                                        data-placement="right"   title=" " data-content="당일의 출입 차량 목록" ></i> <data-trigger="hover"> 출입차량 목록</a></li>                                                

                                    <li><a class="ddmenu"  href="{{url_for('photolog.show_map')}}" class="fa fa-th-list fa-large"> <i data-toggle="popover"  data-container="body" 
                                        data-placement="right"  title=" " data-content="현재 사내에 남아있는 차량의 목록"></i> <data-trigger="hover"> 잔류차량 목록</a></li>                                            

                                    <li><a class="ddmenu"  href="{{url_for('photolog.show_map')}}" class="fa fa-th-list fa-large"> <i data-toggle="popover"  data-container="body" 
                                        data-placement="right" title=" " data-content="기간 중 출입 횟수가 많은 차량 중 상위 n대" ></i> <data-trigger="hover">출입회수 별 </a></li>                                              

                                    <li><a class="ddmenu"   href="{{url_for('photolog.show_map')}}" class="fa fa-th-list fa-large"> <i data-toggle="popover"  data-container="body" 
                                        data-placement="right" title=" " data-content="기간 중 체류시간이 긴 차량 중 상위 n대 " ></i> <data-trigger="hover">체류시간 별</a></li>                                        

                                    <li><a class="ddmenu"  href="{{url_for('photolog.show_map')}}" class="fa fa-th-list fa-large"> <i  data-toggle="popover"  data-container="body" 
                                        data-placement="right" title=" " data-content="입고 후 장기 체류 중인 차량 중 상위 n대" ></i> <data-trigger="hover"> 장기체류 차량</a></li>  

                                    <!-- <a class="dropdown_toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"  href="{{url_for('photolog.show_all')}}" ><i class="fa fa-th-list fa-large"></i> <B>조회/통계 </B> <span class="caret"></span></a>               
                                        <li><a  class="ddmenu" href="{{url_for('photolog.show_map')}}" ><i class="fa fa-th-list fa-large"></i> 출입차량 목록</a></li> 
                                        <li><a  class="ddmenu" href="{{url_for('photolog.show_map')}}" ><i class="fa fa-th-list fa-large"></i> 잔류차량 목록</a></li>
                                        <li><a  class="ddmenu" href="{{url_for('photolog.show_map')}}" ><i class="fa fa-th-list fa-large"></i> 출입회수 별 </a></li>             
                                        <li><a  class="ddmenu" href="{{url_for('photolog.show_map')}}" ><i class="fa fa-th-list fa-large"></i> 체류시간 별</a></li>                   
                                        <li><a  class="ddmenu" href="{{url_for('photolog.show_map')}}" ><i class="fa fa-th-list fa-large" ></i> 장기체류 차량</a></li>    -->                                                                                                                      
                            </ul>
                        </li> 
                    </ul> 
 <!--  Navbar start  ========================  우측 사용자전환/종료 ========================================================================-->       
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right ">

                        <li><a href="{% if session.__contains__('user_info') %}{{url_for('photolog.update_user_form', username=session.user_info.username)}} {% endif %}">
                            <i class="fa fa-pencil" data-toggle="popover" data-container="body" data-placement="top" title=" " data-content="사용자 정보의 등록/수정/삭제 등">
                                </i><data-trigger="hover"><B> 정보 수정 </B></a></li>                                   

                        <li><a id="logout" href="#" class="navbar-link"><i class="fa fa-user" data-toggle=popover data-container="body" data-placement="top" title=" " 
                            data-content="Log off 및 다른 사용자로 log in"></i><data-trigger="hover"><B> SMeMap 종료</B></a></li>  


                        <!-- <li><a href="{% if session.__contains__('user_info') %}{{url_for('photolog.update_user_form', username=session.user_info.username)}}
                                    {% endif %}"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i><B> 정보 수정</B></a></li>
                        <li><a id="logout" href="#" class="navbar-link"><i class="fa fa-user" ><B>SMeMap 종료</B></a></li>  -->                                       
                    </ul>
 <!--  Navbar start  ========================  검색 Button ========================================================================-->       
                    <!--  search form ------------------------------------ -->
                    <form role="form" class="form-inline navbar-form pull-left" action="{{url_for('photolog.search_photo')}}" method="POST">
                    <div class="input-group" style="margin-top: 2px;">
                         <input type="text" name="search_word" class="form-control input-sm search-form" placeholder="검색 차량 정보" {% if search_word %} value='{{search_word}}' {% endif %}>
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm search-btn" type="submit">
                                    <i class="fa fa-search" ></i>
                                </button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </form>                  <!-- /.search-form    -->
                </div>                         <!-- /.nav-collapse -->
            </div>                          <!-- /.container -->
        </nav>

        **<!-- content-------------------------------------------------------->
        <div id="photolog-content" class="col-md-12" style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 30px;">
            {% block content %}{% endblock %}**
        </div> 

        <!-- end of content------------------------------------------------->
        <!-- footer begin -->

        <!-- footer end -->

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#logout').click(function(e){
                bootbox.confirm("로그아웃 하시겠습니까?", function(result) {
                    if(result){
                        window.location="{{url_for('photolog.logout')}}"
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
        <!----------- current page ------------------>    

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've moved the tooltip related data (data-toggle, data-placement, title) under the href.
Originally, it was under the glyphycon, but I moved it.

It's a bit tough, but it's solved once ... -.-
But now moving the mouse, the last dropdown menu is not disqppear.
It is very difficult to use bootstrap. TT

I can not adjust the position of the tooltip ... and I want the background to be yellow, but it does not change color...
Only submenu hover is work.  -.-
Thanks.